# ANN and not using scan for inputs

Tags: c, neural-network, logic

I have my code for a ANN but my professor said we cannot have scan for inputs as it is harder for him to grade due to class size, i have two blocks of code, one with the ANN, and the other without, but i cannot get the code for the second correct. What am i missing?

Result should be 1 1 1 0

EDIT: the sample input should be [image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int s,m,dot,i,j,k,ite;
float iterationError, T = 0.5;
printf("What is the sample size?\n");
scanf ("%d", &s); /* taking input of sample size from user and storing it in s */
printf("Number of inputs  in a sample?\n");
scanf ("%d", &m); /* taking input of # of inputs in a sample from user and storing it in m */
float x[s][m], z[s], n[s], w[m]; /* defining the varible */
for (i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    w[i] = 0; /* initialising the weights to zero */
}
for (i=0;i<s;i++)
{
    printf("Enter the input training data of sample %d\n",i+1);
    for (j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&x[i][j]); /* taking inputs of each sample from user and storing it in matrix x */
    }
    printf("Enter the output of sample %d\n",i+1);
    scanf("%f",&z[i]); /* taking desired output of each sample from user and storing it in array z */
}
for (i=0;i<s;i++)
{
    dot = 0;
    for (j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        dot = dot + x[i][j]*w[j]; /* calculating the dot product of input and their corresponding weights */
    }
    /* assigning the output based on the calculated dot product */
    if (dot > T)
    {
        n[i] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        n[i] = 0;
    }
    iterationError = iterationError+abs(z[i]-n[i]); /* error for initial assumption of weights */
}
printf("Initial output: %f \t%f \t%f \t%f\n",n[0],n[1],n[2],n[3]);
printf("The adjusted weights are:\n");
ite = 0;
/* training the code in a loop to adjust the weights for desired outputs */
while (iterationError > 0.4 && ite < 20){
    ite = ite + 1;
    printf("Iteration: %d ************************************\n",ite);
    for (i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        iterationError = 0; /* making the error zero for new iteration */
        /* updating the weights based on the algorithm given */
        if (n[i]!=z[i])
        {
            if (n[i]==0)
            {
                for (j=0;j<m;j++)
                {
                    w[j] = w[j] + x[i][j];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (j=0;j<m;j++)
                {
                    w[j] = w[j] - x[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%f \t%f \t%f \t",w[1],w[2],w[3]);
        /* calculating the output, as discussed above, based on updated 
         weights */
        for (k=0;k<s;k++)
        {
            dot = 0;
            for (j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                dot = dot + x[k][j]*w[j];
            }
            if (dot > T)
            {
                n[k] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                n[k] = 0;
            }
            iterationError = iterationError+abs(z[k]-n[k]);
        }
        printf("iterationError = %f\n",iterationError);
    }
}
printf("Final output: %f \t%f \t%f \t%f\n",n[0],n[1],n[2],n[3]);
return 0;
  }
```

That is the code for the working code, this is what i have so far when trying to create it without using scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
float trainingData [100][4] = { {1,0,0,1}  , {1,0,1,1}  , {1,1,0,1}  , 
{1,1,1,0} };
float w[100][4]= {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};   //w is weights


int s,m,dot,i,j,k,ite,d;
float iterationError, T = 0.5;
float net;
float z;
int out[4];
if (net>T)
    out[i] =1;
else out[i] =0;

    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    d=0;
    for (j=0;j<2;j++) //out is correct
    {
        net = net + trainingData[i][j]*w[i][j];
    }
    if (net>T)
    {
        out[i] =1;
    }
    else
    {
        out[i] =0;
    }
    for (j=0;j<2;j++)
    {

    iterationError = iterationError + abs(trainingData[i][j]-out[i]);
    }

 }
 printf(" initial output: %f\t %f\t %f\t %f\n",out[0],out[1],out[2],out[3]);
  printf( "the adjusted weights are:\n");

 ite = 0;
 while (iterationError>0.4 && ite < 20)
{
ite = ite+1;
printf("Iteration: %d *******************************\n",ite);
for (i=0; i<3;i++)
{
    iterationError=0;
    if (out[i] != trainingData[i][3])
    {
        if (out[i]==0)
        {
            for (j=0; j<2;j++)
            {
                w[j] = w[j] + trainingData[i][j];
            }
        }
        else
        {
           for(j=0; j<2;j++)
           {
               w[j] = w[j] - trainingData[i][j];
           }
        }
    }
    printf("%f \t %f \t %f \t %f \n", w[0],w[1],w[2]);
    for(k=0;k<3;k++)
    {
        net=0;
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            net = net+ trainingData[k][j]*w[j];
        }
        if (net>t)
        {
            out[k]=1;
        }
        else
        {
            out[k] = 0;
        }
        iterationError = iterationError+abs(trainingData[k]-out[k]);
    }
    printf("iterationError = %f\n",iterationError);
}
}
   printf("Final output: %f \t%f \t%f \t%f\n",n[0],n[1],n[2],n[3]);
   return 0;
  }
```

Im just looking to be pointed in the right direction so that i can learn it.

Comment: Split the input code from the ANN code — put the ANN code into a function, and the input code in another function, and maybe even the printing code into another function.  Then work out how to set up the fixed (no input) data so it matches the unfixed (input) data.  Separating I/O from calculations is often (usually, normally) a good idea — especially input code.

Comment: Note that an MCVE ([MCVE]) would include the sample input data, and the expect vs actual output too.

Comment: You've made your own life hard by changing variable names, and by replacing variables such as `s` with numbers like `3`.  You need to redo the conversion to non-interactive by starting with the working code, and then replacing only the input operations with appropriately initialized data (`int s = 3;` for example).  It isn't clear why you went for `100` as array dimensions; I think 3 and 4 are more nearly appropriate.  I reformatted the code so I could spot these issues. I'm not willing to spend more time, not least because there isn't the data needed for an MCVE so no testing is possible.